# Can I apply the brutal property to Power Strike / Furious Assault?

Tags: dnd-4e

Both Power Strike and Furious Assault add extra [W]'s of damage to an attack.

If the weapon being used is Brutal, does the brutal property extend to the additional [W]'s added from these powers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Anytime you roll dice from a [W] you get to apply brutal. You even get to apply it when you roll high crit [W] dice.